# "No match for operator+"

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, operators

I'm a beginner and getting back to programming after 2 months. Almost forgotten everything. The code I just tried to compile eliminates the second half of the vector usin iterators, if the character I want is found in the first half.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string s("hello world");
    char sought = 'e';
    v.push_back(s);
    auto mid = (v.begin() + v.end())/2;
    if (sought<*mid)
    {
        end = mid;
    }
    cout<<*v;

}
```

Please tell me what my mistake is.

Also, can programming be forgotten? Also, once proficient, do the concept stay forever, or does it require constant practice and reading?

Comment: your code is not valid, where is `end/it` come from?

Comment: You definitely don't want to add Begin to End.

Comment: Plus you never declare `it` or `end`. Correct your basic errors before asking about the algorithm.

Comment: Why not? I realized that, but can I et an explanation please? I'm missing something. Obviously.

Comment: Please show real code, `cout<<*v;` this is not valid, `sought<*mid` won't compile as well.

Comment: Answering your second question, yes some concepts stay forever. Especially those about not using undeclared variables.

Comment: I had written the program in a different way before, and I forgot to edit it completely before posting it here. I didn't use an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you cannot add iterators together (in `v.begin() + v.end()`). Instead, use

```
auto mid = v.begin() + v.size() / 2;
```

Secondly, `end` and `it` are undeclared.

Finally, you cannot erase part of a vector by assigning to "end". You need to use a different method (left as an exercise).

Comment: Worked! Why does v.size() work, but v.end() doesn't? It was given the same way in the book I'm reading, but had no explanation. I'm clearly missing something silly due to my wrong intuition.

Comment: @user2530836: Think about this: What should the type and the value of `v.begin() + v.end()` be?

Comment: I am surprise this works, as `sought` is char and *mid is std::string.

Comment: @NPE, the value will be 11, because that is the number of characters (in the form of a string) present, right? Wouldn't v.begin() + v.size() give the same value?

Comment: I realized my mistake. v.end() computes to the element after the last one. Is that right?

Comment: If vi has 20 elements, then vi.size()/2 is 10 or 9? Considering the first element is of subscript 0.